# I clicked what looked like an Amazon email, but it (maybe) was from an Amazon affiliate. Ended up at Amazon.com anyway. Can I safely investigate?

Tags: malware, xss, virus, phishing, email-spoofing

In a case of clicking too fast, I clicked on a picture that looked like it was from Amazon. However this was not the case. I did end up at Amazon, but I'm aware that other things could've taken place before I landed on the Amazon page.  I immediately disconnected my Ethernet cable.  I hovered my mouse over the link address and did a URL search in virustotal for the domain on another PC and it came back safe. I googled the name in the link I clicked and I saw that the domain was a Amazon affiliate, or so they say. But I still wiped my machine.  However I am still not sure if that link was malicious or not. Knowing whether it was malicious or not has implications for how I move forward and what steps I take to remediate this problem. Is there a safe way to investigate the link and any payload that may have been delivered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What security holes are introduced by clicking an unknown link?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183428/what-security-holes-are-introduced-by-clicking-an-unknown-link), [How do I investigate a suspicious link?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211885/how-do-i-investigate-a-suspicious-link), [Triaging malicious URLs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/203845/triaging-malicious-urls)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Hi Steffen, that does answer my question.  Unfortunately, I'm unable to upvote your comment.  Thank you.